# Proving Chain Rule using Newton's Approximation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Prove that if $X,Y\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $g:Y\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $y_0=f(x_0)$ then $g\circ f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentaible at $x_0$ with $(g\circ f)^\prime(x_0)=g^\prime(y_0)\cdot f^\prime (x_0))$.

So fix $\epsilon >0$

Then there exists a $\delta_1>0$ that if $\vert f(x)-f(x_0)\vert<\delta_1$ then $\vert g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))\vert<\epsilon \vert f(x)-f(x_0)\vert+\vert g^\prime(f(x_0))\vert\vert f(x)-f(x_0)\vert$

This comes from differentiability of $g$ and Newton's approximation.

Let $\epsilon^\prime =\min\{\delta_1,\epsilon_1\vert x-x_0\vert+\vert f^\prime(x_0)\vert\vert x-x_0\vert\}$

Then there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $\vert x-x_0\vert<\delta$ then $\vert f(x)-f(x_0)\vert<\epsilon^\prime$

I know I can satisfy this because of differentiability of $f$.

Then we have if $\vert x-x_0\vert<\delta$, $\vert g(f(x))-g(f(x_0))\vert<\epsilon\cdot\epsilon^\prime+\vert g^\prime(f(x_0))\vert\cdot\epsilon^\prime$

And then $\epsilon\cdot\epsilon^\prime+\vert g^\prime(f(x_0))\vert\cdot\epsilon^\prime\leq \epsilon\cdot\epsilon_1\vert x-x_0\vert +\epsilon\vert f^\prime(x_0)\vert\vert x-x_0\vert+\vert g^\prime(f(x_0))\vert(\epsilon_1\vert x-x_0\vert+\vert f^\prime(x)\vert\vert x-x_0\vert)$

$$=\vert x-x_0\vert\big(\epsilon\cdot\epsilon_1 +\epsilon\vert f^\prime(x_0)\vert+\vert g^\prime(f(x_0))\vert\cdot\epsilon_1\big)+\vert g^\prime(f(x_0))\vert\vert f^\prime(x)\vert\vert x-x_0\vert$$

So from what I can tell I would need to justify that $\epsilon_1$ can be chosen so that $\epsilon\cdot\epsilon_1 +\epsilon\vert f^\prime(x_0)\vert+\vert g^\prime(f(x_0))\vert\cdot\epsilon_1<\epsilon$

But if I take $\epsilon_1<\frac{\epsilon(1-\vert f^\prime\vert)}{\vert g^\prime+\epsilon\vert}$

I don't know that this will be positive however since $1-\vert f^\prime\vert<0$ is possible.